# jQuery Cycle Plugin: Multiple Pagers for different galleries on same page

Tags: jquery, cycle

I've got a single page which has multiple instances of a thumbnail 'cycle' gallery. Problem is though, the Paging system gets all messed up (it's adding all in one or something). It's probably something very simple for you guys, but this is what I've got:

```
$(function(){ 
$('div.gallery')
.before('<div class="imgSelect">')
.each(function() {
$('.imgWrap ul').cycle({
fx: 'fade',
speed: 'fast',
timeout: 0,
pager:  '.imgSelect'
    });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="imgWrap">
    <div class="gallery">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/travel1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/travel2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/travel3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I'm basically trying to say, for each div called '.gallery', add a Pager div (.imgSelect) before it - but all these pagers should count only the images within that gallery.

Any help would be much appreciated,
Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work:

```
$(function() {
    $('.gallery ul').each(function(i) {
        $(this).before('<div class="imgSelect imgSelect'+i+'">').cycle({
            fx:     'fade',
            speed:  'fast',
            timeout: 2000,
            pager:  '.imgSelect' + i
            });
        });
    });
```

**note**: the timeout is in millisecond, setting it to zero will stop the cycle :D

hth.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('div.gallery').each(function() {

        $(this).before('<div class="imgSelect" />');

        $('.imgWrap ul').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 'fast',
            timeout: 0,
            pager:  '.imgSelect'
            });
        });
    });
```

that will add `div.imgSelect` before each `div.gallery`

tho i'm not sure waht you mean with:

> but all these pagers should count only
>   the images within that gallery

oh ic, try this one:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.gallery').each(function(i) {
        $(this).before('<div class="imgSelect imgSelect' + i + '" />');
        $('.imgWrap ul').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 'fast',
            timeout: 0,
            pager:  '.imgSelect' + i;
            });
        });
    });
```

this will add a second class imgSelect0 through imgSelectN, where N is the total number of galleries minus one. the plugin internal counter keep adding the number if the assigned pagers are the same, so a work around is assigning distinct pager selector for each gallery.

Comment: Thanks, what I mean is that the Pager is appearing, but it's counting all the images within the page, not the images for that div. So instead of paging say 4 images, it's paging 12 because there are 12 in the page.

Comment: Oops, and I should add, that the actual 'cycling' is not even happening! So there's something drastically wrong!

Comment: i tried modifying the sample that come with the plugin, making 2 gallery with pagers, and it works. the difference is the cycle() function attached to $('div.gallery') instead $('.imgWrap ul') so i think you wrote your html differently

Comment: ah ic, you put the images inside <li>s, a sec