# Div displaying entire array need it to display only one value at a time

Tags: jquery, cakephp, html, foreach, jquery-cycle

I have this page that displays pictures in a div.  I have jquery cycle to display these images in a slideshow.  I'd like to have the slideshow be manual, and have a slides navigation div that displays on top of the images for navigation.  The problem is, no matter where I stick my 'slides' div, it is retrieving the links for every single image result on my page (not just each result on the page).  For better reference, please visit [this link](http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/lodgings/condos). If you inspect the element you will see that the div class="slides" takes what appears to be every image in the entire array and sets a link. (I realize that where I have the div right now makes it take every image in the entire array).  I've tried setting this above the php code, right below the foreach, inside the foreach and even completely outside the 'thumbs' div (which is where it is supposed to reside), with no change in results.  And to make matters worse, I have a z-index problem that is causing my nav to display below all the images, even though the z-index is set correctly.  So in order to see my results, I have to 'inspect element' in Chrome or turn off images to see what's going on.  Anyone have a clue?

```
<?php 
                      $p=array($condo['Unit']['photo1'],$condo['Unit']['photo2'],$condo['Unit']['photo3'],$condo['Unit']['photo4']);
         echo '<div class="slides"></div>';          
                      if($condo['Unit']['photo1']!=''){


                            foreach($p as $value) {
                                echo '<a href="/complexes/';
                                echo $condo['Complex']['complex_name'];
                                echo '/';
                                echo $condo['Unit']['unitnum'];
                                echo '"><img src="';
                                echo $value;
                                echo '" style="width:240px; height:160px" /></a>';
                                }
                           echo '</div>';
                        }
                       elseif($condo['Unit']['photo1'] == '') {
                              echo '<a href="/complexes/';
                              echo $condo['Complex']['complex_name'];
                              echo '/';
                              echo $condo['Unit']['unitnum'];
                              echo '"><img src="/img/img_unavailable.png" /></a>'; 
                        }
                ?>
```

Comment: ** Update: I fixed my z-index problem, the div is now displaying on top correctly.

Comment: I should also mention that the variable $condo is itself an array of results ($allcondos as $condo), if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.  The problem was definitely in my code for the slideshow.  I modified my php slightly, like so:

```
if($condo['Unit']['photo1']!=''){
                            echo '<div class="thumbs">';

                            foreach($p as $value) {
                                if($value !='') {
                                    echo '<a href="/complexes/';
                                    echo $condo['Complex']['complex_name'];
                                    echo '/';
                                    echo $condo['Unit']['unitnum'];
                                    echo '"><img src="';
                                    echo $value;
                                    echo '" style="width:240px; height:160px" /></a>';
                                    }
                                }
                           echo '</div>';
```

Then, here is what my JQuery cycle script looked like:

```
<script>

$(function() {
$('.thumbs').each(function(i) {
    $(this).append('<div class="overlay slides'+i+'">').cycle({
        fx:  'fade',
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 0,
        pager:  '.slides' + i,
        slideExpr: 'img'
        });
    });
});
```

and it worked!  I used this thread as a reference to get me started:  [Multiple Plugin pagers for different galleries on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354285/jquery-cycle-plugin-multiple-pagers-for-different-galleries-on-same-page).

I removed the before() callback and added append().  Yippee!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question correct. 
This is my observation:
The cycle plugin has all images as immediate children of the div that used to initiate plugin. Where as you've links as immediate children and then images.

Also you have an extra closing div or a missing opening div.
If you're using CakePHP, why not use HTML helper to render links, images and other tags? It is quite useful and your code looks cleaner.(just my opinion)

Comment: Ok, I fixed the problem with the unclosed div tag.  I removed the a tags around my images.  The cycle plugin is still for some reason pulling the results of every image in the results, not just the images for each particular unit.  As for using the HTML helper I will definitely do that. Cleaner code is always better.

Comment: **Update:  The problem is definitely in JQuery, not PHP.  I am working through a solution and will post once it works.